# My Regex has slow performance, who can optimize it?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently working on a regex, which match some content inside a html file.

As example:

```
  <h3>    
    {{wf-content-footer_support_title}}
        FOOTER SUPPORT TITLE
    {{./wf-content-footer_support_title}}  
  </h3>
```

Or:

```
  <h3>    
    {{wf-content-footer_support_title}}FOOTER SUPPORT TITLE{{./wf-content-footer_support_title}}  
  </h3>
```

Currently I have the following regex, which is working for a small amount of matches. If I have more than 3 matches the regex hangs up in an endless loop. After research I found out that my regex has bad performance. But I don't know how to change it for better performance:

```
{{wf-content-(.+)}}(?:|\s+)(.+)(?:|\s+)+{{\.\/wf-content-.+}}
```

I hope someone can optimize it for me.

EDIT:
Part of my code:

```
  private static Regex _wfContentRegex = new Regex(@"{{wf-content-(.+)}}(?:|\s+)(.+)(?:|\s+)+{{\.\/wf-content-.+}}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

...
...

```
foreach (var htmlTemplate in htmlTemplates)
        {
            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlTemplate);

            var mc = _wfContentRegex.Matches(htmlDocument.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
            foreach (Match match in mc)
            {
                var content = new Content
                {
                    Key = match.Groups[1].Value,
                    Description = match.Groups[2].Value
                };

                if (ContentManager.GetContents().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Key.ToLower() == content.Key.ToLower()) == null)
                {
                    AddContent(content);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew he's not parsing HTML.

Comment: Thanks, but I already use it, I edited the first post with my code.

Comment: Your regex is not that complex...

Comment: @SP7: Good, then a tip is to not forget to keep the question lean and mean so that no one could think you are using regex to parse HTML :) Use `InnerText` to get the text without the HTML around it.

Comment: @Thomas okey? but it always hangs up after the third iteration in the inner foreach. And if I test it on a webtester as regexr or something else. It says operation timeout. Do you have an idea where does my problem comes from?

Comment: *the third iteration* => what's the value of it?

Comment: The problem with the regex is that there is a nested quantifier `(?:|\s+)+`. When inside a pattern, it can have impact when there is no match.

Comment: Try with this `{{wf-content-(\w+?)}}\s*(.+)\s*{{\.\/wf-content-\w*}}`

Comment: And looking at your code, you are parsing HTML with regex. The correct way would be to find the `h3` you need with an XPath, and then get your text from the `Value`, or `InnerText`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having issues because your matches are eager. That means they'll match as many characters as possible, and if the rest of the expression can't be matched, it'll backtrack and see if the rest of the expression can match at an earlier point. I would suggest having stricter end-of-"tag" matches, like

```
{{wf-content-([^}]+)}}\s*(.*\S)\s*{{\.\/wf-content-[^}]+}}
```

To make it more robust, you could use a back-reference in your end-tag. Not sure how this is done in the C# flavor, in POSIX regexp it would look like this

```
{{wf-content-([^}]+)}}\s*(.*\S)\s*{{\.\/wf-content-\1}}
```

But the first one should work fine for not-so-strict stuff.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you!
Just for your information: The second works as well in C#

Comment: Just FYI: the second `\s*` in `\s*(.+)\s*` makes no difference, the `(.+)` matches it unless there is a newline (if `RegexOptions.Singleline` is not used). In C#, you can declare it as `var pattern = @"{{wf-content-([^}]+)}}\s*(.*?)\s*{{\./wf-content-\1}}";` (though I think you should be using the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option here).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, good catch. I used non-eager match instead as an exmaple, so anyone reading this, either the non-eager in Wiktor's comment or the one above. Both should work.

Comment: BTW, you should not be afraid of using a lazy dot matching pattern in .NET regex, it is much more stable than in JS/PCRE/Python/Java.

Comment: .. and I of course meant, that I used an *eager* match in my edit, as an example, compared to Wiktor's *non-eager*... I need coffee.